# why cat() just execute the first "\n" in parameter "labels"

Tags: r, cat

I wrote the following code to test how the "labels" parameter of cat() works:

```
df <- data.frame(A=1:3, B=4:6, C=7:9)
cat(summary(df), file="df.txt", fill=102, sep="\n ", labels=c("A\n", "B\n", "C\n"))
```

I hope the file "df.txt" looks like:

```
A
 Min.   :1.0  
 1st Qu.:1.5  
 Median :2.0  
 Mean   :2.0  
 3rd Qu.:2.5  
 Max.   :3.0  

B
 Min.   :4.0  
 1st Qu.:4.5  
 Median :5.0  
 Mean   :5.0  
 3rd Qu.:5.5  
 Max.   :6.0  

C
 Min.   :7.0  
 1st Qu.:7.5  
 Median :8.0  
 Mean   :8.0  
 3rd Qu.:8.5  
 Max.   :9.0
```

But I get:

```
A
 Min.   :1.0  
 1st Qu.:1.5  
 Median :2.0  
 Mean   :2.0  
 3rd Qu.:2.5  
 Max.   :3.0  

B\n Min.   :4.0  
 1st Qu.:4.5  
 Median :5.0  
 Mean   :5.0  
 3rd Qu.:5.5  
 Max.   :6.0  

C\n Min.   :7.0  
 1st Qu.:7.5  
 Median :8.0  
 Mean   :8.0  
 3rd Qu.:8.5  
 Max.   :9.0
```

My question is that why the first "\n" of labels works and the other don't?

Comment: At first glance, this looks like a bug.  Here's a shorter reproduction of this behavior: `cat(c('a', 'b'), fill=1, sep="\n", labels=c('A\n', 'B\n'))`

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, if it's a bug, then I could leave it behind.